# Правильный способ отправки пароля на сервер (динамическая соль)

Tags: php, безопасность, хеширование, пароль

Как выглядит полный алгоритм проверки пользователя с применение динамической соли? Какие данные следует отправлять на сервер?

Отправляются:

1. login
2. hash = hash(hash(pass) + salt);
3. salt

Или применяется какой-то иной алгоритм?

Comment: На клиенте — отправка обычного пароля через HTTPS. На сервере — bcrypt/scrypt/PBKDF2/Argon2. И не слушайте никого, кто предлагает просто MD5 с солью и другие подобные вещи — они уже считаются ненадёжными лет десять как.

Comment: Я вот читал, что отправка пароля обычным текстом через https - это не панацея. Рекомендуется отправлять именно хеш с добавлением соли, но нигде не говорится нужно ли отправлять саму соль отдельно, если не хранить ее в базе?

Comment: Почему не панацея? Разве что если хочется скрыть пароль от сервера, но зачем? Вроде бы HTTPS общепринято считается достаточно надёжной мерой защиты ([не без недостатков](https://habrahabr.ru/post/332730/), но в целом норм)

Comment: @andreymal почему с солью не надежно? если соль не константа?

Comment: @Пашка `Рекомендуется отправлять именно хеш с добавлением соли,` - понимаете, в этом нет никакого смысла. Т.к. хэшировать вы будете в данном случае на клиенте. А код на клиенте спокойно берется из браузера и разбирается на запчасти. То есть там лежит всё в открытом виде. В итоге самые супернавароченные алгоритмы - просто пыль и ничто, т.к. к ним имеется доступ

Comment: Ну это понятно, что всегда найдется дыра. Но тут ведь суть в том, что бы обеспечить максимальную надежность передаваемых(!) на сервер данных(пароль учетки). Одно дело я отправляю обычный текст, другое дело я отправляю хеш, и совсем третье, когда передаю хеш с солью.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский соль всего лишь предотвращает подбор паролей для всех юзеров сразу, а на скорость перебора для отдельно взятого юзера не влияет вообще никак (ну может радужные таблицы станет труднее юзать, но это мелочи)

Comment: @andreymal радужные таблицы могут быть на простые хэши, максимум на константные простые соли. вряд ли существуют таблицы для динамической соли, алгоритм которой кто-то сам придумал. Это из разряда фантастики........ а подобрать простой пароль (например ДР юзера) методом перебора можно в любом случае, не зависимо от сложности алгоритмов хэширования.

Comment: @Пашка `Одно дело я отправляю обычный текст, другое дело я отправляю хеш, и совсем третье, когда передаю хеш с солью.` - скажите пожалуйста  какая в этом разница, если я знаю ваш алгоритм хэширования и солирования для передаваемого пароля?

Comment: @Пашка хотел бы предложить вам кое-какой вариант с вопросом: убрать метку `PHP`, дописать в вопросе предложение типа такого: "например больше всего интересует как можно это сделать в PHP, но и общая информация нужна". - в итоге свести вопрос в более общий, нежели в конкретный язык. Мне кажется люди могли бы подтянуться.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну от простого пароля уже ничего не поможет, нет смысла их рассматривать. А непростой даже шестисимвольный даже по самым оптимистичным прикидкам будет подбираться при Argon2I двадцать тысяч лет). А на MD5 даже тщательно солёный уйдёт всего месяц-другой, если даже на дохлом ноутбуке подбирать

Comment: @andreymal то есть даже у меня соль "некий хеш от сегодняшнего числа +  id в базе + еще какя-то хрень - это реверснуто, разбито пополам, переставлены половины и захешированы еще раз"?))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский какая разница какая соль? Она всегда заранее известна — все известные мне алгоритмы хэширования паролей хранят соль рядом с хэшем. Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: @andreymal по-моему вы сейчас говорите о моменте, когда БД уже взломали, а не нахождение пароля не зная алгоритма и не имея доступа.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну да, я во всех своих комментариях говорил именно о взломанной БД. Безопасность через неясность? Ну хз-хз, на один сайтец на моих глазах залили пхп-шелл, уверен, там вместе с БД увели и весь пхп-говнокод со всеми алгоритмами))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский > скажите пожалуйста какая в этом разница, если я знаю ваш алгоритм хэширования и солирования для передаваемого пароля?
Ну на сколько я успел понять смысл заключается именно в увеличении времени, которое понадобится злоумышленнику для получения исходного пароля.

Answer (score 1):

Логин и пароль вы получаете от пользователя и оправляете путем `post` на сервер там у вас прописана стандартная ваша соль, ее никто крове сервера не знает и передавать ее не нужно.

При регистрации вы тоже добавляете соль и храните hash в базе, поэтому получив от пользователя данные сверяете hash в базе и созданный вашим скриптом.

Если хотите генерировать разную соль то можно сделать скрипт в котором вы добавите саму соль в хеш, и только вы будете знать длину соли в самом пароле вот как пример: `$salt . sha1($salt . $string);` а создать соль тоже можно автоматом: `$salt = substr(md5(time()), 0, $saltLenght);` Переменная `saltLenght` задаст на сколько нужно обрезать соль.

**ps** в php версии 5.5 сейчас есть своя функция генерации и проверки паролей с солью [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php)  а проветрить можно через  [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: Так и в чем тогда смысл соли? Или я храню пароль и сверяю с тем что передается через post или храню пароль и соль, и к post паролю добавляю ее и получаю опять тот же пароль. Смысл лишних действий с соль, какую безопасность такого алгоритм дает?

Comment: Смысл в том чтобы получив hash невозможно было узнать реальный пароль клиента. И злоумышленник не может подменить у вас данные, т.к. проверка идет на уровне сервера. А вы уже после авторизации выдаете токен или что либо другое.

Comment: @Пашка если ваш сервер взломают и украдут базу данных, злоумышленникам придётся помучаться, чтобы из солёных паролей получить исходные несолёные — смысл солей в этом

Comment: я все это прекрасно понимаю. Но в комментарии описан следующий алгоритм:
1. БД хранит хеш и соль.
2. post передает просто хеш пароля
3. сравниваю (post хеш пароля + соль из БД) == (хеш из БД).

Все правильно? Зачем в этой схеме соль? Если хеш пароля может быть похищен при передаче и потом применен злоумышленником, он таким же образом передаст этот же самый хеш, который опять потом не сервере сложится с солью в БД? Меня чето это схема смущает...

Comment: @Пашка, передавать в запросе хэш вместо пароля - это абслютно бесполезно.

Comment: @Qwertiy а я разве говорил, что надо передавать вместо пароля?

Comment: @Пашка, цитирую: _"2. post передает просто хеш пароля"_

Answer (score 0):

"Динамическая соль" не имеет никакого смысла - сервер-то про неё не знает! А ваша задача уже давно решена математиками: SRP-6! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol

Answer (score -1):

[MD5 и другие алгоритмы хеширования.](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.md5.php)

Да вы можете создавать двойной хеш строки и даже добавлять соль.

Comment: Это я понимаю, что могу создавать. Но меня интересует что я должен отправить на сервер каждый раз когда ввожу данные пользователя? я должен отправить хеш пароля с солью и дополнительно саму соль? Или это не правильно и какой-то иной алгоритм лучше применять?

Comment: MD5, даже солёный, вскрывается на ура банальным подбором, если длина пароля до 8-9 символов (а такой пароль у большинства)

Comment: @Пашка пользователь отправляет пароль.. все хэширования, соленья, приготовления делаются на сервере

Comment: @АлексейШиманский [SCRAM предлагает солить-хэшировать и на клиенте тоже](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5802) (правда, в безопасности этого предложения я ещё не разбирался)

Comment: @andreymal я не буду это всё читать)) но предположу там что-то написано вроде: генерировать соль на сервере, отсылать на клиент, на клиенте применять соль для хэширования и отсылать обратно, а там опять с этим что-то делать?

Comment: @andreymal SCRAM и всякие CHAP - это способы аутентификации которые устойчивы к подмене сервера. Т.е. подменив сервер хакер не сможет узнать пароль (однако, это не делает протоколы автоматически устойчивыми к Relay-атаке). Для HTTP подобные механизмы полностью бесполезны потому что если хакер "сидит" на канале до сервера - он может подменить клиентский скрипт.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский // cc